# not able to show data for edit

Tags: java, html, jsp

My data is in "data" variable I want to show all the data on click of edit button my edit button is on another jsp.Data in "data" variable comes in both cases(new entry and to edit) from database  How to do that task plz help me.

```
    <%
          String [][] data=null; int i=0; int j=0;
           String mode="";
         if(request.getAttribute("advRemittanceData")!=null)
         {
         data=(String [][])request.getAttribute("advRemittanceData");
       }
        mode=(String)request.getAttribute("mode");
         %>
     <script>
      var count = "0";
     function addRow(in_tbl_name)
    {


        count = parseInt(count) + 1;


                                                                                     document.getElementById(in_tbl_name).getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];

        var row = document.createElement("TR");

        var td1 = document.createElement("TD")
        var table = document.getElementById(in_tbl_name);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.style.width = "4%";
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "checkbox";
        cell1.appendChild(element1);


        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.style.width = "15%";
        var element4 = document.createElement("select");
        element4.style.width = "100%";
        element4.setAttribute("id", "compCode_"+count);
        element4.setAttribute("name", "compCode_");
        element4.setAttribute("style", "width:200px");
        element4.setAttribute("maxlength", "1000");

        <% if(data!=null){
            for(i=0;i==0;i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<data[0].length;j++)
                {%>
              option= document.createElement('option');
              option.text = '<%=data[i][j]%>';
              option.value = '<%=data[i][j]%>';
              element4.options.add(option);
        <%}}
        }%>
         cell2.appendChild(element4);

        var td2 = document.createElement("TD")
        var id3="importar_"+count;
        var strHtml3 = "<input type='text'  maxlength='500' style='width:100%;' name='importar_' id='"+id3+"'/>";
        td2.innerHTML = strHtml3;



        var td3 = document.createElement("TD")
        td3.style.width = "15%";
        var id4="iec_"+count;
        var strHtml4 = "<input type='text'  maxlength='10' style='width:100%;' name='iec_' id='"+id4+"'/>";
        td3.innerHTML = strHtml4;


        var td4 = document.createElement("TD")
        var id5="amount_"+count;
        var strHtml5 = "<input type='text'  maxlength='10'  style='width:100%;'name='amount_' id='"+id5+"'/>";
        td4.innerHTML = strHtml5;


        var td5 = document.createElement("TD")
        var id6="document_"+count;
        var strHtml6 = "<input type='text'  maxlength='10'  style='width:100%;'name='document_' id='"+id6+"'/>";
        td5.innerHTML = strHtml6;

       row.appendChild(td2);
       row.appendChild(td3);
       row.appendChild(td4);
       row.appendChild(td5);


        <%
            mycount=mycount+1;
        %>
        //tbody.appendChild(row);

    } 

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try 
        {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
</script>

<body>
<table align="left" >
            <TR>
                <TD>
                    <input type="button" id="firstaddrow" value="Add" onclick="addRow('tablebody')" tabindex="1"/>
                    <input type="button" id="seconddeleterow" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow('tablebody')" tabindex="2"/>
                </TD>
            </TR>
            </table>
<table border ="1" id="tablebody"  cellpadding="1" align="center" width="160%" >

</table>
</body>
```

Comment: check whether `data=(String [][])request.getAttribute("advRemittanceData");` its returning any value or not??

Comment: yes brother it's return an array.

Comment: Is any1 is there to help me out?

Comment: use option.innerText or try to alert the value of option.value.